# iPhone Device iOS 4.3.5 returns 1970 instead of current date when using [NSDate date] Simulator works fine

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, nsdate

My device used to have no problem returning the correct date from NSDate, but now all of a sudden, it isn't working.  I've rebooted my device, nothing changes.  NSDate returns a date from 1970.

I started noticing this strange behavior when using an app I wrote (only on my device, simulator works fine), where a call to [NSDate date] returned some bizarre date from 1970.  I was so puzzled that I tried creating a brand new test project.  After creating the project, I simply added the following one line of code in the app delegate's application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: message:

```
NSLog(@"Current Date: %@", [NSDate date]);
```

The log shows the following:
1970-01-12 00:04:53.-66 BP_DateTest[112:707] Current Date: 1970-01-12 04:04:53 +0000

My iPhone is currently running iOS 4.3.5 and this is an iPhone 4 device.

When I use the iOS calendar app, everything looks fine, it shows the current date correctly.  I went into settings, and checked the international settings, and the calendar is set to Gregorian with United States format.

Please - does anyone have a clue what this is all about?  It used to work just fine, so I have no idea what has happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1970-01-12 00:04:53.-66 BP_DateTest[112:707] Current Date: 1970-01-12 04:04:53 +0000
```

The `1970-01-12 00:04:53` output in the debugger says that your device is set to 1970.
Check under `Settings` -> `General` -> `Date & Time` -> `Set Date & Time`

Comment: It was set to 'Set Automatically', so apparently that isn't working.  I turned that feature off, and manually set the date/time correctly.  Though this has solved my problem, it makes absolutely no sense how my calendar was correct and anything else involving date/time on the device worked fine...Thanks